# Какую подстановку Value лучше всего использовать в sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Пишу подстановки в виде:

```py
cur.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES ("%s")' % user_id)

cur.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
```

На что лучше всего заменить подстановку с `("%s")` ? Часто делают замечания по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта плохи. Для передачи параметров нужно использовать другую конструкцию

```
cur.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id=?',(user_id,))
```

Это защитит вас, например, от SQL инъекции. Также, например, не нужно устанавливать `'`